# running fast dynamic programming algorithm to get all the answers

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization

how i could run fast dynamic programming algorithm to get all the possible answers .
imagine we have 20 entries and it only shows 1 line of best answers , i want it to run all the way and show the others too, till all the entries are shows as a result, and no repetitions is allowed .
thank you so much. really appreciate it.
here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

float W ,N; //N = olcu sayisi, W = profil boyu
vector<float> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

pair<float, multiset<float>> calc(float i, float j) //returns closest sum and best subset of the first i numbers for the target value j
{
    static map<pair<float, float>, pair<float, multiset<float>>> dp; //stores results to avoid repeated calculations

    pair<float, float> p(i, j); //pair for convenience

    if(i == 0) //base case
    {
        return make_pair(0, multiset<float>(
                                      {}));
    }

    auto findResult = dp.find(p);

    if(findResult != dp.end()) //check if already calculated
    {
        return findResult->second;
    }

    auto temp1 = calc(i - 1, j); //compute result if not using number

    if(numbers[i - 1] > j) //if current number is too big
    {
        return temp1;
    }

    auto temp2 = calc(i - 1, j - numbers[i - 1]); //compute result if using number
    temp2.first += numbers[i - 1];
    temp2.second.insert(numbers[i - 1]);

    pair<float, multiset<float>> result;
    if(temp1.first != temp2.first) //compare results and choose best
    {
        result = temp1.first > temp2.first ? temp1 : temp2;
    }
    else
    {
        result = temp1.second.size() < temp2.second.size() ? temp1 : temp2;
    }
    dp[p] = result;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "sineklik sayisi: ";
    cin >> N;
    N = 2 * N;
    cout << "Profil olcusu: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations

    cout << "Olculeri giriniz: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        float temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }

    pair<float, multiset<float>> result = calc(N, W); //calculate

    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << result.first << " Left behind is " << W - result.first << ", obtained using the set of numbers {";
    if(result.second.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << *result.second.begin();
        for(auto i = ++result.second.begin(); i != result.second.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << ", " << *i;
        }
    }
    cout << "}.\n";
}
```

Comment: All possible answers is a pretty steep problem. Douglas Adams worked on it for quite a long time and the best he could do was 42

Comment: well we have to take the next best then , showing the best possible sums of entries will do, but we have to show all entries , with no repetition 
for example :
entries: 10,20,30,40,50,60
target sum : 70
answer : {10,60},{50,20},{30,40}
-----
now it only shows {10,60} for answer
sincerely appreciate it guys

Comment: @user4581301 could you please help me guys ?
appreciate it .

Comment: I'm working on it dude no need for another question. Most people don't even know what you are talking about without reading the code.

Comment: @FeiXiang thank you so much , i know i can count on you , sincerely appreciate it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This is one of my older answers. I wasn't as good back then, and now I know there is a much simpler, faster, and less memory-consuming solution to this problem. If we compute the DP bottom-up in a table that only stores the closest possible sum, we can reconstruct the subsets recursively later using the table values we computed.

A solution that outputs all sets of numbers with sum equal to the greatest possible sum not greater than the target value and containing the least possible number of numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int N, W; //N = number of numbers, W = target sum
vector<int> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> calc(int i, int j) //returns closest sum and best subset of the first i numbers for the target value j
{
    static map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, set<multiset<int>>>> dp; //stores results to avoid repeated calculations
    pair<int, int> p(i, j); //pair for convenience
    if(i == 0) //base case
    {
        set<multiset<int>> temp;
        temp.emplace();
        return make_pair(0, temp);
    }
    auto findResult = dp.find(p);
    if(findResult != dp.end()) //check if already calculated
    {
        return findResult->second;
    }
    auto temp1 = calc(i - 1, j); //compute result if not using number
    if(numbers[i - 1] > j) //if current number is too big
    {
        return temp1;
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> temp2 = calc(i - 1, j - numbers[i - 1]), newtemp2; //compute result if using number
    newtemp2.first = temp2.first + numbers[i - 1];
    for(const auto k : temp2.second)
    {
        multiset<int> temp = k;
        temp.insert(numbers[i - 1]);
        newtemp2.second.insert(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> *result;
    if(temp1.first != newtemp2.first) //compare results and choose best
    {
        result = temp1.first > newtemp2.first ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else if(temp1.second.begin()->size() != newtemp2.second.begin()->size())
    {
        result =
                temp1.second.begin()->size() < newtemp2.second.begin()->size() ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.second.insert(newtemp2.second.begin(), newtemp2.second.end());
        result = &temp1;
    }
    dp.insert(make_pair(p, *result));
    return *result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter target sum: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> result = calc(N, W); //calculate
    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << result.first << ", which can be obtained using a set of "
            << result.second.begin()->size() << " numbers " << result.second.size()
            << " different ways:\n";
    for(const auto &i : result.second)
    {
        cout << '{';
        if(i.size() > 0)
        {
            cout << *i.begin();
            for(auto j = ++i.begin(); j != i.end(); ++j)
            {
                cout << ", " << *j;
            }
        }
        cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

This solution will not allow a number to appear in the output more than the number of times it appeared in the input. If you want to only allow a number to appear once in the output even if it appeared multiple times in the input, change the multiset `numbersleft` to a set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int N, W; //N = number of numbers, W = target sum
vector<int> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> calc(int i, int j) //returns closest sum and best subset of the first i numbers for the target value j
{
    static map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, set<multiset<int>>>> dp; //stores results to avoid repeated calculations
    pair<int, int> p(i, j); //pair for convenience
    if(i == 0) //base case
    {
        set<multiset<int>> temp;
        temp.emplace();
        return make_pair(0, temp);
    }
    auto findResult = dp.find(p);
    if(findResult != dp.end()) //check if already calculated
    {
        return findResult->second;
    }
    auto temp1 = calc(i - 1, j); //compute result if not using number
    if(numbers[i - 1] > j) //if current number is too big
    {
        return temp1;
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> temp2 = calc(i - 1, j - numbers[i - 1]), newtemp2; //compute result if using number
    newtemp2.first = temp2.first + numbers[i - 1];
    for(const auto k : temp2.second)
    {
        multiset<int> temp = k;
        temp.insert(numbers[i - 1]);
        newtemp2.second.insert(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> *result;
    if(temp1.first != newtemp2.first) //compare results and choose best
    {
        result = temp1.first > newtemp2.first ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else if(temp1.second.begin()->size() != newtemp2.second.begin()->size())
    {
        result =
                temp1.second.begin()->size() < newtemp2.second.begin()->size() ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.second.insert(newtemp2.second.begin(), newtemp2.second.end());
        result = &temp1;
    }
    dp.insert(make_pair(p, *result));
    return *result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter target sum: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> result = calc(N, W); //calculate
    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << result.first << ", which can be obtained using sets of "
            << result.second.begin()->size() << " numbers:\n";
    multiset<int> numbersleft;
    numbersleft.insert(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    for(const auto &i : result.second)
    {
        bool good = true;
        for(const int &j : i)
        {
            if(numbersleft.find(j) == numbersleft.end())
            {
                good = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(good)
        {
            for(const int &j : i)
            {
                numbersleft.erase(j);
            }
            cout << '{';
            if(i.size() > 0)
            {
                cout << *i.begin();
                for(auto j = ++i.begin(); j != i.end(); ++j)
                {
                    cout << ", " << *j;
                }
            }
            cout << "}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've modified your code and the answer let me show you how it reacts , for 30 entries the result is this :
The best possible sum is 598 left behind 0, which can be obtained using the set of numbers:
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 109.2, 114.8, 158.8}
The best possible sum is 598 left behind 0, which can be obtained using the set of numbers:
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.2, 113.8, 158.8}
The best possible sum is 598 left behind 0, which can be obtained using the set of numbers:
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.8, 113.2, 158.8}

Comment: {19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 109.2, 114.8, 158.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.2, 113.8, 158.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.8, 113.2, 158.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.8, 123.2, 148.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 110.8, 133.2, 138.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 111.2, 112.8, 158.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 111.8, 112.2, 158.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 111.8, 122.2, 148.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 69.8, 113.8, 120.2, 148.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 77.8, 109.2, 116.8, 148.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 77.8, 110.2, 115.8, 148.8}
{19.8, 57.8, 67.8, 77.8, 111.2, 114.8, 148.8}
and so on

Comment: as far as i could understand , this shows all the answers , we need only 1 answer for each sequence of numbers , for example imagine we have [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90] for entries , target sum is 100, answers should be : {10,90}{20,80}{30,70}{40,60}{50} , but now its acting like this : {10,90}{10,20,70}{10,30,60}{10,40,50} and so on ... , sincerely waiting for your kind reply , than you so much

Comment: my deer friend , if we could make the code to calculate best possible sum of given numbers without repeating the numbers, we are done , sums should be as near to given max as possible , thank you so much , waiting for your reply

Comment: Can you give me your code? It seems like it might be a mistake on your part or it could have something to do with floating point error. I never tested the system with floats.

Comment: The newest version of my code in this answer should only give the sets with the least number of numbers.

Comment: yes my dear friend i think there is a problem with floats , inputs are floats so i tried changing integers to floats , but its not working very well with floats , I'm waiting for your kind reply

Comment: and its not showing all the answers , the first code that you wrote , was working like a charm, but it had the only problem of limiting the out put for one line , i think maybe reviewing that would be better, our goals are : 1. show all the entries as result , 2. no repeating in the results , 3. best possible sums (ether its the given max or any other sum as near to max as possible), thank you Fei

Comment: I don't understand what else you want... There is a version for only showing one possible solution, or showing all possible solutions with the greatest sum, or showing all possible shortest solutions with the greatest sum. Give me a few examples of input and output.

Comment: my dear friend , number of numbers = 30 , target =598 , inputs:75,85,95,100,105,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,145,150,155,160,165,170,175,180,185,190,195,200,205,111,222,333,444,123. output :
{75, 190, 333},{85, 180, 333},{95, 170, 333},{100, 165, 333},{105, 160, 333},{110, 155, 333},{115, 150, 333},{120, 145, 333},{125, 140, 333},{130, 135, 333}, as you see its repeating numbers , when a number is shows on the output , it shouldn't be on any further lines ,we want to calculus best way to reach target by using all the given numbers without repeating them. thank you so much.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it. I'll think about it.

Comment: Do you want to allow a number to appear twice if it's given in the input twice?

Comment: @hesamrastad Done.